# The use of strcat in C overwrites irrelevant strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, stack

The code is as follows:

```
char seg1[] = "abcdefgh";
char seg2[] = "ijklmnop";
char seg3[] = "qrstuvwx";

strcat(seg2, seg3);
```

Then the value stored in seg1 will become:

`"rstuvwx\0\0"`

I have learned to declare that strings with close positions are also adjacent in the stack area, but I forgot the details.

I guess the memory address of seg1 was overwritten when strcat() was executed, but I'm not sure about the specific process. Can someone tell me the specific process of this event？Thanks

Comment: Arrays in C are not dynamic. The size you use at their definition is the exact size they will have for the rest of their life-time. All the arrays you show will have the size `9` (remember the null-terminator). When you attempt to append to `seg2` then you will write out of bounds of the array, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: String handling in C is hard and tedious, unless you write or find a string library which supports dynamic strings...

Comment: Oh, I understand what I did wrong. I'm sorry I overlooked that.

So this error depends on how the compiler stores these strings in memory. In this example, `seg1` is placed behind `seg2` in memory by the compiler, so the overwriting behavior occurs, right?

Thank you. Your words enlightened me@Some programmer dude

Comment: @goon, "so the overwriting behavior occurs, right? " --> No.   When you _attempt_ to append to `seg2` then you have _undefined behavior_.  It might overwrite, it might not.  Code may crash or not.  It is _undefined behavior_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not have a string class, it has character arrays which may be used as strings by appending a null terminator. And since there is no string class, all memory management of strings/arrays must be done manually.

`char seg1[] = "abcdefgh";` Allocates space for *exactly* 8 characters and 1 null terminator. There is no room to append anything else at the end. If you try anyway, that's the realm of *undefined behavior*, where anything can happen. Crashes, overwriting other variables, program ceasing to function as expected and so on.

Solve this by allocating enough space to append something in the end, for example
`char seg1[50] = "abcdefgh";`. Alternatively allocate a new, third array and copy the strings into that one.